# Align generated text in center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ewJ4L/)**

I display text with an animation using third party plugin, now after animation completed my html look like this

```
<div data-cj-randomize="false" data-cj-loop="false" class="cj-fx cj-fx-text-link" id="effect-1" style="font-size: 32px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); width: 850px;"><a class="cj-fx-spacer">&nbsp;</a>
    <a data-cj-scale-y-end="1" data-cj-scale-y-start="0" data-cj-rotate-x-end="0" data-cj-rotate-x-start="90" data-cj-buffer-y="70" data-cj-buffer-x="70" data-cj-animate-opacity="true" data-cj-easing="Circ.easeInOut" data-cj-duration="5000" data-cj-animation-delay="0" data-cj-start-delay="0" data-cj-animate-by-word="false" data-cj-sequence="forward" data-cj-direction="in" data-cj-type="flyTopCenter" class="cj-fx-text" target="_blank" href="#" style="">
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">T</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 31px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">h</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 55px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">e</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 77px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">m</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 114px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">e</span>
        <span style="position: static; left: 136px;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 149px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">f</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 164px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">o</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 190px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">r</span>
        <span style="position: static; left: 207px;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 220px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">O</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 256px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">p</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 281px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">e</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 303px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">n</span>
        <span style="position: static; left: 327px;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 340px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">C</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 373px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">l</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 385px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">a</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 407px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">s</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 426px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">s</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 445px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">r</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 462px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">o</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 488px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">o</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 514px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">m</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 551px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">s</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 570px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">&ndash;</span>
        <span style="position: static; left: 595px;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 608px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">T</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 639px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">O</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 675px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">I</span>
        <span style="position: static; left: 692px;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 705px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">M</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 749px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">a</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 771px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">r</span>
        <span style="position: static; left: 788px;">&nbsp;</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; transition-property: opacity, left, top, -moz-transform; transition-duration: 5s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86); opacity: 1; left: 801px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">1</span>
        <span style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; left: 826px; top: 0px; transform: rotateX(0deg) scaleY(1); position: static;" class=" cj-tween">3</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to set the text in center using jquery

Comment: How do you maintain this markup? It hurts my eyes.

Comment: Such questions don't usually get a second glance, simply looking at the code gave me a headache.

Comment: You're making your position fixed with the "top" and "left". Try to remove those and use text-align center (unless it really has to be done through jquery)

Comment: @undefined: i have used third party plugin to get animation effect, i wrote a line and plugin seperated each character into span and so apply flying effect, so this was the generated markup, sry for this unreadable markup

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the code re-format, a labor of love!

Comment: What is the jQuery plug-in that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center your final text line, you need to have the following CSS rules:

```
#effect-1 {
    text-align: center; /* add this */
}

.cj-fx-text {
    position: absolute; /* remove this */
    top: 0; /* remove this */
    left: 0; /* remove this */
}
```

This could be implemented using the jQuery `.css()` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you get rid of this

```
<a class="cj-fx-spacer">&nbsp;</a>
```

and change .cj-fx-text to:

```
.cj-fx-text {
    perspective: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ewJ4L/1/

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Change css

```
.cj-fx-text {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    left: 0;
    perspective: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ewJ4L/3/)